# "They've raised their hand" vs "They've raised their hands"?

Tags: objects

Consider these two phrases:

> “They've raised their hand”
>   “They've raised their hands”

Does object have to agree with subject? To make the question more clear, let's assume all of them have raised their right hand/hands(?). Now we have five people and five raised hands.

**I've changed the original question which used idiom "to show one's true colors" as example, which was giving the idea that my question was about usage of the specified idiom. I apologize for my poor choice of example.**

Comment: It sounds like a pirate convention, if they show black flags ;) _colours_ means _flag_. If they would be showing hands, you can use the singular if each of them shows one hand: _five people raised their hand_, although _their hands_ would not be wrong — but _hands_ might mean each person raised both their hands.

Comment: You need to give a more descriptive example. In "Five people are showing black color.", I have no idea what *black color* really is. Also you should edit the title to follow your example, and remove "They've shown their true colors" as is causes confusion with the idiomatic expression as you already noted.

Comment: @user3169 I've edited the question. Is it any better now?

Comment: The question now avoids one interesting idiom, but I'm afraid it now is a duplicate. This question has been asked in several shapes and forms... The question I linked to uses _hands_ in the answer.

Comment: Changing a question so considerably that given answers become completely and totally unrelated may lead to confusion, by the way. I will remove my answer because it has nothing to do with the question as it stands now.

Comment: @oerkelens I understand this and apologize for the same.

Comment: I've closed the question as a duplicate, but there's no need to apologize – that just means it's such a good question someone has happened to ask it already. :^) (If you want, though, you could roll the question back to the original question about the idiom, and we could undelete the answers.)